# OCCI SQLExceprion & terminateConnection

Tags: sqlexception, occi

I'm new in OCCI programming and I have one question.
I'm writing a Linux daemon, which connetcts to an Oracle database. Sometimes database server breaks connection(or db admin kills session), in that case I catch an SQLException. My question is: how should I correctly terminate OCCI connection after catching an exception?
P.S. terminateConnection method throws the same exception and I get an endless loop or uncatched exception with programm aborting.

Comment: I'm facing this same scenario. My initial thought is to call `terminateEnvironment` on the OCCI Environment if `terminateConnection` throws an error.

Comment: What's the exception being thrown? If there's an open statement one needs to terminate that first.